# onEdit, breakApart, are not working as planned

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Currently the code is not working

```
function onEdit() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Class');
var level = sheet.getRange('K3').getValue();
var class = sheet.getRange('L3').getValue();
  if (class === "Warlock") {
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
    sheet.getRange('A7:D7').mergeAcross();
  } else if (class === "Fighter") {
      sheet.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
      sheet.getRange('A7:B7').mergeAcross();
    } else {
    }
```

it is saying to break and merge cells based on `class` and it is not recognizing and nothing is happening. The debugger says it's fine but I cant seem to see what's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You're `break`ing`Apart` and `merge`ing`Across` the same range. So, it's broken and merged. So, nothing seems to happen: if it was merged before, it'll stay merged at the end after breaking.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it like this it toggles between Warlock and Fighter and you can see the slight variation in the merging especially if you highlight A7:D7.  I just stuck a checkbox in A1 to get it to toggle.

```
 function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast('Flag1');//remove after debug
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()!='Sheet1')return;
  var class = sh.getRange('L3').getValue();
  e.source.toast('Flag2');//remove after debug
  if (class=="Warlock") {
    e.source.toast('Flag3');//remove after debug
    sh.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
    sh.getRange('A7:D7').mergeAcross();
    sh.getRange('L3').setValue('Fighter');//remove after testing    
    sh.getRange('A7:D7').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);//remove after testing
    sh.getRange('A7:D7').setBackground('#ffff00');//remove after testing
  } else if (class=="Fighter") {
    e.source.toast('Flag4');//remove after debug
    sh.getRange('A7:D7').breakApart();
    sh.getRange('A7:B7').mergeAcross();
    sh.getRange('L3').setValue('Warlock');//remove after testing
    sh.getRange('A7:B7').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);//remove after testing
    sh.getRange('A7:D7').setBackground('#ffffff');//remove after testing
    sh.getRange('A7:B7').setBackground('#ff00ff');//remove after testing
  }
}
```

Comment: So why are there ```'Flag1'``` ```'Flag3'``` ```'Flag2'``` ```'Flag4'```

Comment: I  use that for debug.  Much of the time the script doesn't work right off the bat so I have to debug it.  Mostly, the problems are typos due to my old fingers and too small of a keyboard.